# Calculating path through 3d points

Tags: algorithm

How would I take a group/array of 3d points in space and calculate a path from 1 point to another, given a limit to the distance that can be jumped, so it may be necessary to jump to another point first? While also trying to minimize the total distance traveled.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest path problem on a graph. Your 3d points are the vertices in a graph. There is an edge between two vertices if their distance is shorter than your jump distance limit. Then just run shortest path.

Comment: So after calculating all first points within the given distance, do I then need to calculate all their points in distance for each, or is there a method to gauge which points are likely in the direction of the destination?

Comment: please see here for the shortest path algorithm:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm      this finds shortest path for arbitrarily large graph.   the problem here is mostly how to transform your problem so that it can be solved by this algorithm.   to do this just abstract out the distance between points and forget about 3d.    (to enforce jump limit you can remove edges longer than the limit).

Comment: My point is moreso what if the closest point to current location, is actually farther from the destination then a point that is farther, how do I account for moving backwards in that?

Comment: the beauty of the algorithm is that you don't need to. it accounts for it automatically. you can think of it as a magic box that automatically gives you the best answer. to see why you need to read its proof.